# Netbeans occasional non-compilation using Ruby MRI – solution?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, compilation, jruby

Quite frequently when I save changes to a Ruby file in Netbeans and try to run the file, the interpreter simply doesn't do anything. The only way around it is to temporarily switch to the JRuby interpreter and then switch back to the default Ruby interpreter (1.86). Besides this hack, is anyone aware of a fix for this problem? It has pretty much made Netbeans an unworkable IDE for my Ruby coding as a result.

Netbeans 6.5/No plugins/Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Ruby 1.9? Probably wouldn't fix the kind of problem you're experiencing but might be interesting to see if it works any differently than 1.86.

Comment: Funny you say that - I've been using 1.9 the last few days and it seems ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thats strange. i´ve been using netbeans for ruby development since it´s in there. could you tell us your version number and any plugins you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this will help... but I have been using Netbean 7.0MS1 for a while now at it is pretty stable (Netbeans does a very good job of beta/MS software).  Also next week the early release of 6.7 is coming out apprently.  Possibly one of the newer versions will magically fix your issue.

http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0/m1/